# JSP Java Code inside ajax jquery prompt nullpointer exception

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, jsp

This code is inside the function **submitForm(){}**, means, everytime when user click the save button it will trigger this part. the code shows no error, but during the page load, it gives this error:

**`PrintDebug.println("Final SeqNo: "+finalSeqno);`**
**%>**
**`<%ResultSet rsVal = aDBManager.retrieveRec(sqlgetSeq);%>`**

**`<%if(rsVal.next()){ %>`**

**[Stacktrace:] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException**

I have tried to remove this part of code,and everything work as expected.Seems like the resultset of the select statement giving me the error.for the stored proc resultset , it works fine. This actually confuse me, why the stored proc is ok but not the select statement in ajax jquery.If this can't be done, is there another way for me to pass the value from select statement to input label?

Thanks in advance..

```
callback: function (result) {
    if(result){
        var forTempValue = "";
        var forFieldValue = "";
        var forMandatory = "";
        var forDataImageNoApp = "";
        var loopInt = 0;
        $('input[type=textbox][name^=tmpField],select[name^=tmpField],input[type=text][name^=tmpField]').each(
                function(index){  
                    var input = $(this);
                    forTempValue+=("'" + input.prop('value').replace(/&/g,"") + "' Col" + loopInt + ",");
                    forFieldValue+=("'" + input.prop('value').replace(/&/g,"") + "'" + "±");
                    loopInt++;
                }
        );
        $('input[type=hidden][name^=MandatoryName]').each(
                function(index){  
                    var input = $(this);
                    forMandatory+=(input.val() + ",");
                }
        );
        $('input[type=hidden][name^=tempNoAppLoop]').each(
                function(index){  
                    var input = $(this);
                    forDataImageNoApp+=(input.val() + ",");
                }
        );
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
        url: "../ESSCheckerMakerOperation",
        data: "sTabID=<%=sTabID%>&sFieldNameApp=<%=sFieldNameApp%>",
        success: function(msg){
            <%
            String getSeqNo = "SELECT MAX(fldSeqno) FROM "+MappingID+"";
            String finalSeqno="";
            ResultSet rs = aDbManager.retrieveRec(getSeqNo);
            if(rs.next()){
                finalSeqno=rs.getString(1);
            }rs.close();
            String cmd="EXEC sp_RelationshipValidation  '"+MappingID+"'," + finalSeqno;
            aDbManager.SQLTransaction(cmd);
            String sqlgetSeq= "Select fldCommonErrorFlag " +
                      " From tblGeneralError" +
                      " Where fdSeqNo '" +finalSeqno  + "' "+
                      " And fldTableName = '" +MappingID  + "' ";


        PrintDebug.println("Final SeqNo: "+finalSeqno);
        %>
        <%ResultSet rsVal = aDBManager.retrieveRec(sqlgetSeq);%>

        <%if(rsVal.next()){ %>

            document.getElementById('lblError').style.visibility = 'visible';
            document.getElementById('lblError').innerHTML = <%=finalSeqno%>;
            Ko
            <%}else{%>  

            bootbox.alert({
                title:"Record is successfully ",
                message:"There is a problem with the validation for" + <%=finalSeqno%> ,
            });
            <%
            }%>
        //}
        },
        error: function(msg){
            bootbox.alert({
                title:"Error",
                message: "Failed to save the record.",
            });
        }
        });
    };
}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really a classic one: The key is to realize, **where** and **when** which code is executed - JSP on the server when the page is requested and rendered (i.e. **before** the response is send to the browser) and Javascript in the browser, **after** the browser receives the already generated response.

Your main mistake is to use JSP scriptlet in the `success` handler of the AJAX call - the scriptlet is run on the server side, **before** when the page is generated, i.e. **before** the AJAX request can even be fired by the browser. Thus, the variables you expect to be filled by the call are `null`.